# I'm trying to do a taskscheduler and am getting this error message

Tags: r

My script looks like this

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test_run2", rscript = "C:/Fol1/FOLD2/Fol3/Folder 4/Good Folder 5/Folder-6/Folder7/1_Load_Files.R", 
                 schedule = "MONTH", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 50, "%H:%M"),startdate = format(Sys.Date()+1, "%m/%d/%Y"), modifier = 1)
```

The script on its own works. I have issue when i change the parameters to daily or monthly and it then does not work.

I get this error message

```
"ERROR: Value for '/TR' option cannot be more than 261 character(s)."
 attr(,"status")
 [1] 16389
```

Comment: Character limits are annoying if this works how I think then it's the a command line limit in windows. Try putting the script in a shorter folder path.

Comment: I just did. Unfortunately it didn't work. I got a similar message.

Comment: `Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'schtasks /Create /TN "test_run2" /TR "cmd /c C:/Users/NAME~1/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-42~1.1/bin/Rscript.exe \""C:/Fol1/FOLD2/Fol3/1_Load_Files.R\"  >> \"C:/Fol1/FOLD2/Fol3//1_Load_Files.log\" 2>&1" /SC MONTHLY /MO 1 /ST 16:24 /SD "12/17/2022" /D * /M * ' had status 16389`

Comment: same error since 2017 and it's 2024. M$ does not care the least.